# How to get Real Ads by Admob into iphone

Tags: iphone, sdk, admob, ads

I am getting the Test Ads everytime in my iphone from Admob Service.

I want to get the real Ads.

I have tried the following but doesn't seem to work.

```
-(BOOL)useTestAd
 {

       return NO;

 }
```

I have ios SDk 4.2 in my Mac.

How can I get real Ads?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to have an Account in the Admob site.

Then you need create(register) an App in your account. Then you will get a publisher id.

you have to use that publisher id in the code at some place in the Admob sdk file or some where else.

Then you will get the real ads.

All the best.

Regards,

Satya